# in DDD, when I don't want navigation property from child to parent, is it still needed at least a property for the ID of the parent?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have this:

```
Class Order
{
    long ID;
    ...
}

Class Item
{
    long Id;
    IdProduct;
    decimal Amount;
    ...
}
```

Perhaps I misunderstood what means bidirectional relation in DDD, because I have read that if it is possible, it is better to have only navigation from parent to child, and not from child to parent, but I don't know if navigation means not to have in the child a property of type order but I need a long property for the ID of the parent or not navigation from child to parent means to have a long property for the ID parent too.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand correctly but if you don’t want a navigation properly from the child to the parent, simply give the parent a collection of children.

Comment: You may be thinking about relational databases, database records and foreign keys? There is no reason to do this with objects.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam Yes, I was thinking more from a database point of view, thinking how to map this case in EF Core, if the item has not a property with the ID of the order. But really from a point of view of DDD I don't need this.